# Hiding / showing markers: OSMDroid / OpenMaps

Tags: osmdroid, markers

I have an app which uses or googlemaps or openMaps (offline) depending of connection state.

In each case there are markers, for places or point of interest or… I want that the user can display or hide some category of markers.

When using google maps I have a menu and in the action bar when some item is selected it toggles between showing or hiding the markers from the correpondent category; As for google maps that works easily & perfectly using  `isVisible();`

As for osmdroid i have not found in the doc any equivalent to `isVisible()`, neither any `show()` or `hide()` method. So I have tried to use as a workaround `somemarkers.getAlpha()` & `somemarkers.setAlpha()`, toggling between `0` & `1` alpha values.

No error occurs but the visibility of markers remains the same, not toggling, or only randomly when i tap 10 or 20 times on the action icon.

In the log i get `"InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed"` which seems to me to be the cause.

But what to do to avoid this?

KitKat, SonyXperia Z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In osmdroid, the method to hide/show overlays (markers) is:

Overlay.setEnabled(boolean enabled)

Comment: i try this as soon as possible and tell you; thanks in advance

Comment: your solution worked...but mine too! - toggling betwween 1 & 0 for setAlpha() changes the visibility IF you (the user) move the map - what i have not done till now!- just a little; if he does not, the update is not called; i have added map.invalidate() and now it runs...

Comment: setAlpha(0) works for markers. But it is really a weird solution: the marker is still drawn, just to show... nothing. Other drawback: if a bubble has been set on it, the invisible marker will still react to tap, and the bubble will open.

Comment: yes, you are right; so i have found (because i like to look at...) another "workaround" which seems perfect and runs very quickcly: setting the position of markers outside of the boundingbox when the user wants to hide them and restoring the initial coordinates, fom an arrayList, when he wants to show them. But many thanks!

Comment: Funny :-) but even worst => now you have to track map panning/zooming events, playing cat and mouse to move your markers outside the view... setEnabled() is the method you should use.

Comment: Beware!!! FolderOverlay silently does not respect enabled: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/1155

Answer (score 0):

I have done this bit differently.

1. Extend ItemizedIconOverlay
2. Add as an overlay to mapView
3. Hide markers by using removeAllItems or removeItem
4. Show marker by adding it to the itemized overlay list

Create a new Overlay class by extending ItemizedIconOverlay.
Note: WaypointOverlayItem extends OverlayItem. {It's your custom overlay model class}

```
        public class NavigatorItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedIconOverlay<WaypointOverlayItem> {

        private Context mContext;

        public NavigatorItemizedOverlay(final Context context, final List<WaypointOverlayItem> aList) {
            super(context, aList, new OnItemGestureListener<WaypointOverlayItem>() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemSingleTapUp(int index, WaypointOverlayItem item) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongPress(int index, WaypointOverlayItem item) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mContext = context;
        }
      }
```

Add this Overlay to your map

```
      //Add Itemized overlay
        navigatorItemizedOverlay = new NavigatorItemizedOverlay(getActivity(), waypointOverlayItemList);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(navigatorItemizedOverlay);
```

To Add marker:

```
navigatorItemizedOverlay.addItem(waypointOverlayItem);
```

To hide all markers:

```
navigatorItemizedOverlay.removeAllItems();
```

There are other methods:

```
removeItem(position) and removeItem(waypointOverlayItem)
```